# Почему-то пишет, что вызов неопределенной функции imagecreatefrompng(). Хотя все должно работать

Tags: php, функции, php8

```
<?php
    $imagePath = __DIR__.'./images/blank.png';
    $fontPath = __DIR__.'./9605.ttf';

    $image = imagecreatefrompng($imagePath);

    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,0);
    $text = 'Deezer13';

    imagettftext($image, 50, 0, 100, 100, $color, $fontPath, $text);

    imagepng($image, __DIR__.'./result.png');
    imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6KEF.png

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Надо установить расширение `gd` для `php` и раскоментить строку `extension=php_gd.dll` в `php.ini`

Comment: У меня такого файла нету

Comment: А ну я файл нашел, только не могу найти эту строку extension=php_gd.dll

Comment: посмотри в этом файле в разделе "extensions", там что-то вообще gd или gd2 есть? Если нет, значит тебе надо устнаовить это расширение., как я и написал в самом начале

Comment: Можешь пж помочь с еще одним вопросом?
Если да, то вот ссылка: 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1516650/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-ziparchive-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d1%8f-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e

Comment: То есть ответ тебя ничему не научил?) ну нет у тебя расширения zip значит и надо установить и раскоментить в разделе extensions в php.ini

Comment: Научил, я это и сделал, но все равно не работает

Comment: я решил проблему. Оказалось, что надо было перезапустить сервер после изменения php.ini