# Почему-то выдает ошибку, что класс ZipArchive не найден, хотя я его создаю

Tags: php, классы, php8

```
<?php
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zipFile = '29.zip';

    if ($zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== true) {
        exit ('errors');
    }

    $zip->addFile('text.txt');

    echo $zip->filename;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $zip->numFiles;
    echo '<br>';

    $zip->close();
?>
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: про разные вещи пишите. Пхп вам и говорит, то вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр, а он не знает, что это за класс. В стандартный пакет он не входит, там пхп компилировать надо с флагами, или в ини включать расширение

Answer (score 0):

класс **ZipArchive** реализован в отдельном модуле PHP. Если вы получаете ошибку, что класс не найден, это значит что либо модуль не установлен, либо он установене подключен.

Более подробно кто винова и что делать -  можно почитать в инструкции на модуль на сайте PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/zip.installation.php